# Should my index.html file be a text file?

Tags: html, css, web

so i am pretty new to this and i was wondering if the index.html file for my site is supposed to be a text file (also, i'm on Windows 10). When i create the index.html file in file explorer the file that makes the most sense to me is a text file. (The files are: bitmap image, contact, rich text document, text document, and compressed zipped folder), So i would assume i'm supposed to pick text document. The folder ends up looking like index.html.txt, not sure if this is how i'm supposed to do it.

Comment: `index.html` should probably be an `html` file, not a `.html.txt` file.

Comment: When it comes to "save as".. if you're writing it in notepad, save as .. all files and type the .html extension

Comment: 1) If on Windows 10, I can strongly recommend switching on the "File name extensions" checkbox in the View ribbon. 2) if you end up with a _folder_ named index.html.txt, you're doing it wrong. 3) If you create any kind of new file other than Text Document, you can always rename the extension and then edit the premade content out of it with Notepad; no worries.

Answer (score 0):

Start notepad, or an editor of your choice.
Type in the content you want for your file.
Save-As “Index.html” in the location you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the file extension is in the name itself ".html" just the same as a Cascading Style Sheet (CSS) file would be saved as a ".css" file and a Javascript file as ".js"

Everything after the "." is the type of file.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, everyone above answered correctly.  You want to save the file in a plain-text format with a .html at the end.  Then you can open it in a browser like Internet Explorer and it will interperate the file as an HTML page.

You can use a program like [CoffeeCup](https://www.coffeecup.com/free-editor/) to easily edit HTML files and it will save them as plain-text.

You can't edit HTML files in rich-text editors like Word.